# How to find index from raw and column in python?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I would like to use in np.put() function, but it requires, target indices, interpreted as integers.

**[Problem:]** I know raw and column, but now I need to find an index.
In my case I have matrix 6 by 6 and I would like to find an index of data[3,3].

```
heatmap = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=int);
index? = someFuction(heatmap[r,c]);
```

I have tried to use functions like where(), enumerate() and shape(), but it didn't work.

It should be a very basic solution, but I couldn't find it anywhere online.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html):

```
import numpy as np
heatmap = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=int)
index = np.ravel_multi_index([[3], [3]], heatmap.shape)
print(index)
>>> [21]
```

Comment: Cannot help, why not simply calculate `3*6+3`, or generally: `row*numberOfColumns + column`? Too much C and C++ programmer???

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, that's another option. The function is just a convenience, among the many that NumPy provides, to avoid errors in repetitive tasks (it also has some extra functionality, like C/Fortran order choosing, out-of-bounds handling and works for arbitrary number of dimensions, although those are not really relevant to this question). Not sure one is more C/C++ than the other, if I were programming in C++ I'd probably write a function to do that I there weren't any in my lib :)